# Custom customer area tab not showing as current due to no controller name

Tags: magento2, action

I have set a new page in the customer area with link that links to my new controller with below code:

```
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-address-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Address Book</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/index/products</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
```

My controller is like below:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Customer\Index;

class Products extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

protected $resultPageFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
}
}
```

This creates a link fine and can visit my controller URL however the link within navigation is not set as "current".

Upon investigating `vendor/magento/framework/view/element/html/link/current.php` where the **`isCurrent`** function works out if this is the current page i can see that my controller does not seem to be given a controller name.

```
 $this->_request->getControllerName();
```

Does return the controller name however but the getMCA function does not seem to build it into the full path.

```
return $this->getCurrent() || $this->getUrl($this->getPath()) == $this->getUrl($this->getMca());
```

So for my controller it's showing that `/customer/contract/products != /customer/contract` and so not current however it is and just want to know why this function is not working as expected here.

So I was wondering if anyone knows where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging i think i have figured out that this is due to the use of the word index in any of the module / controller / action getting ripped out in the `getMCA()` function and so if it's its also present in URL it should not be as index will be used by default:

```
 if (!empty($value) && $value != $this->_defaultPath->getPart($key)) {
            $parts[] = $value;
        }
```

I changed my controller name to contract and set the action name to index. Then set the url within customer navigation to `/customer/contract` these now match, however setting url to `/customer/contract/index` although works, does not match.